# Usage of "whereabouts"

Tags: word-usage

Is a noun "whereabouts" used not only for something moving (e.g. person)
but for something still?
For example:

```
Do you know his whereabouts?
```

vs

```
Whereabouts of the building they searching is still unknown.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can used both as a *noun* and as an *adverb*.

-I don't know *whereabouts* he comes from. (Adv)

-His *whereabouts* is still a mystery to me.(noun)

*Whereabouts of the building they are searching is still unknown*

It simply means the place where someone or something is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer what I think you're asking. Yes, you can say "He told me the whereabouts of the building" even though it doesn't change. The definition of it is "the place where someone or something is" according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I broadly agree with Josh61 and Ron Kyle. However, in my opinion:

-- As a noun, "whereabouts" is treated as a plural.

-- It is not a count noun (see http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/noun_exercise.htm), so it must be preceded by a suitable determiner (http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm).

So, "Whereabouts of the building they are searching is still unknown" should be "The whereabouts of the building they are searching are still unknown"